# Rigorous way of creating an escape sequence for delimiters

Tags: c#, regex, string, escaping, delimiter

Example Text: *(John, 36, Alabama)*

What I am doing in my code is first matching the round brackets () and then splitting the content within using a comma as the delimiter.

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetValues(string value)
{
  var matches = Regex.Matches(value, @"\(.*\)");
  if (matches.Count == 0) return new string[0];

  var valueSplit = matches[0].Value;
  var theString = valueSplit.Trim('(', ')');
  var wordSplit = theString.Split(',').Select(x=>x.Trim());
  return wordSplit;
}
```

For a sample text *(John, 36, Alabama)* the above code returns:

- John
- 36
- Alabama

Now the problem is that how am I supposed to create an escape sequence for the comma, that I've used as the delimiter.

Such that for a sample text (John 36, Alton,*<-something before this comma* Alabama) returns

- John
- 36
- Alton, Alabama

and recursively allows me to even escape the escape sequence itself ? I have tried my head around *String.Replace* and *Regex.Replace* but to no avail.

Heres a [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lbzobI)

Comment: If you know that only one field can contain comma (and it is placed at the end), then you can limit the number of splits to the number of expected fields.

Comment: Two thoughts.  First, one way of coping with this (CSV style) is to wrap a field containing the delimiter in quotes, so that any comma included in quotes is not a delimiter.  Another way of dealing with this is to choose a delimiter that is not a comma.  Comma is really not a very good delimiter.  Can you choose a different delimter, say a '|'?

Comment: @DWright I absolutely agree that comma isn't the best delimiter out there but unfortunately I cannot make any changes to the current setup. Except finding a way of escaping the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

if you only ever want 3 substrings then you could limit that from the Split

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        foreach (var item in GetValues("(John, 36, Alabama, Whatever, Manager)"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetValues(string value)
    {
       var matches = Regex.Matches(value, @"\(.*\)");
       if (matches.Count == 0) return new string[0];

       var valueSplit = matches[0].Value;
       var theString = valueSplit.Trim('(', ')');
        var wordSplit = theString.Split(new char[]{','}, 3, StringSplitOptions.None).Select(x=>x.Trim());
       return wordSplit;
    } 
}
```

Output:

- John
- 36
- Alabama, Whatever, Manager

Here's the [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/64v7HK)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the right way of escaping the delimiter, at-least in my case, as there can be more than 3 values.

Comment: did you take a look at the fiddle link? with this you can have as many a you want, but only the first 2 will be separately and everything else will be in the third split (including your delimiters)